# Segmentation fault (core dumped) error C linux sockets

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, coredump

Please help me this program should send files via sockets, but it shows the error segmentation fault when I run it.
The server uses thread to implement  multiple clients. 
Thanks! It's my final project!!

This is the server code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>    
#include<stdlib.h>    
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h> 
#include<unistd.h>    
#include<pthread.h> 
static const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
//CREAR HILO
void *connection_handler(void *);

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int socket_desc , client_sock , c , *new_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;


    //CREAR SOCKET
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1) //ERROR AL CREAR EL SOCKET
    {
    printf("ERROR AL CREAR EL SOCKET");
    }
    puts("SOCKET CREADO"); //SOCKET CREADO

    //VALORES DEL SOCKET
    server.sin_family = AF_INET; //SOCKET IP
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; // EJECUTAR CON LA IP DE LA MAQUINA ACTUAL
    server.sin_port = htons(9999);//PUERTO

    //ASOCIAR SOCKET A UN PUERTO
    if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
    // ERROR EN LA ASOCIACION
    perror("ERROR AL ASOCIAR EL SOCKET AL PUERTO DEL SERVER");
    return 1;
    }
    puts("PUERTO CREADO EN EL SERVER CORRECTAMENTE");

    //MODO ESCUCHA CONEXIONES ENTRANTES
    listen(socket_desc , 3); // TRES CONEXIONES PERMITIDAS

    //ACEPTA CONEXIONES ENTRANTES
    puts("A LA ESPERA DE CONEXIONES ENTRANTES");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    while( (client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c)) ) // CONEXION ACEPTADA 
    {
    puts("CONEXION ACEPTADA");

    pthread_t sniffer_thread;
    new_sock = malloc(1);
    *new_sock = client_sock;

    if( pthread_create( &sniffer_thread , NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) new_sock) < 0)
    {
        perror("NO SE PUDO CREAR EL THREAD");
        return 1;
    }


    }

    if (client_sock < 0)
    {
    perror("FALLO");
    return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

/*
 * HABILITAR VARIAS CONEXIONES
 * */
void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
{
    //SOCKET
    int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;     
        char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];

        while(1)
        { 

       FILE * fpIn = fopen("/mnt/SHARED/La.Lista.De.Schindler.Latino.avi", "r"); //ARCHIVO A ENVIAR
           ssize_t bytesRead = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), fpIn);
           if (bytesRead <= 0) break;  // EOF

           printf("Se han leido %i bytes del archivo, enviandolos ...\n", (int)bytesRead);
           if (send(sock, buf, bytesRead, 0) != bytesRead) // ENVIAR EN EL SOCKET
           {
              perror("AL ENVIAR!!");
              break;
           }
        }

    //LIBERAR EL SOCKET
    free(socket_desc);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the client code

```
#include<stdio.h> //printf
#include<string.h>    //strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>    //socket
#include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr

static const int BUFFER_SIZE = 16*1024;

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server;

    //CREAR SOCKET
    sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (sock == -1)
    {
        printf("NO SE PUDO CREAR EL SOCKET");
    }
    puts("EL SOCKET FUE CREADO");

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); // IP SERVER
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;//SOCKET IP
    server.sin_port = htons(9999); //PUERTO

    //CONECTAR AL SERVER
    if (connect(sock , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        perror("LA CONEXION FALLO");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("CONEXION ESTABLECIDA\n");

            FILE * fpIn = fopen("/home/soporte/PELI", "w");//ARCHIVO RECIBIDO
            if (fpIn)
            {
               char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];
               while(1)
               {
                  ssize_t bytesReceived = recv(sock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
                  if (bytesReceived < 0) perror("RECEPCION");  //ERROR AL RECIBIR
                  if (bytesReceived == 0) break;   //SE CIERRA LA CONEXION AL FINAL DEL ARCHIVO

                  printf("Se han recibido %i bytes desde la red, escribiendo a un archivo...\n", (int) bytesReceived);
                  if (fwrite(buf, 1, bytesReceived, fpIn) != (size_t) bytesReceived)
                  {
                     perror("fwrite");
                     break;
                  }
               }

               fclose(fpIn);
            }
            else printf("Error, no se pudo abrir el archivo [%s]\n", "/home/soporte/ESTEBAN");

    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is the Seg Fault? Did you try using GDB?

Comment: where is `Segmentation fault` at server side or client side?

Comment: if `bytesReceived < 0` you should not go on to `fwrite`.

Comment: Closely read the man-pages for recv()/send() and learn that those two functions do not necessarily receive/send as much bytes as they were told to, but few. So looping around such calls counting until all data expected had been received/sent is a good idea, not to say an essential necessity.

Answer (score 0):

In your server code you open your file continuously in `while....loop`. is it for any purpose?

Your handler in Server looks like as follows

```
/*
 * HABILITAR VARIAS CONEXIONES
 * */
void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
{
       //SOCKET
        int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;     
        char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];
        FILE * fpIn = fopen("/mnt/SHARED/La.Lista.De.Schindler.Latino.avi", "r"); 
        while(1)
        { 

          //ARCHIVO A ENVIAR
           ssize_t bytesRead = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), fpIn);
           if (bytesRead <= 0) break;  // EOF

           printf("Se han leido %i bytes del archivo, enviandolos ...\n", (int)bytesRead);
           if (send(sock, buf, bytesRead, 0) != bytesRead) // ENVIAR EN EL SOCKET
           {
              perror("AL ENVIAR!!");
              break;
           }
        }

    //LIBERAR EL SOCKET
    free(socket_desc);
    fclose(fpIn);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
new_sock = malloc(1);
```

for

```
new_sock = malloc(sizeof(*new_sock));
```

And make sure that in connection_handler function, when you try to open the file, you really do it. (fpIn > 0)
Otherwise, you should break the while.